# Unable to get streaming intraday bar data with bloomberg api wrapper blp

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi

```
from blp import blp

with blp.BlpStream(setDefaultSubscriptionService="//blp/mktbar") as bs:
    bs.subscribe({"/ticker/ES1 Index": {"fields": "LAST_PRICE","options": "interval=1"},
                 })
    
    n = 0
    for ev in bs.events(timeout=120):
        print(ev['correlationIds'],[ev['element']["MarketDataEvents"][fld] for fld in ["PRICE_LAST_TIME_RT","LAST_PRICE"]])
        # or just print(ev)   
        n += 1
        if n > 3:
            break
```

Expecting OHLC bars, and since not specifying start and end times should be the current trading session.

Always times out; Does not seem to be receiving any events.  Tried bar_size instead of interval, as well as different combinations of the ticker, and specifying times and not at all.

Some docs and comments seem to indicate that //blp/refdata should be used, instead of //blp/mktbar.  But neither work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use the OP's code, it fails at the `subscribe()` call, telling me the session has not been started. Even if it had worked, there are subsequent problems.

This code works for me, with an explicit session start, and gives an output every minute (using `bar_size` rather than `interval`):

```
from blp import blp

ohlc = {'OPEN':None, 'HIGH': None, 'LOW': None, 'CLOSE':None}

def updateOhlc(flds):
    for k in ohlc.keys():
         if k in flds.keys():
             ohlc[k] = flds[k]

bs = blp.BlpStream(setDefaultSubscriptionService = '//blp/mktbar')

bs.session.start()

ticker = '/ticker/SPX Index'

subs = bs.subscribe({ticker: {'fields': 'LAST_PRICE','options': 'bar_size=1'},})

if subs[ticker]:
    n = 0
    for ev in bs.events(timeout=120):
        if n>=9:
            break

        msgType = ev['messageType']
        elt = ev['element']
        fields = elt[msgType]

        if msgType == 'MarketBarStart':
            if n==0:
                updateOhlc(fields)

            print(fields['TIME'],ohlc)
            n+=1

        updateOhlc(fields)
```

with output:

```
18:04:00 {'OPEN': 4005.29, 'HIGH': 4006.42, 'LOW': 4005.24, 'CLOSE': 4006.42}
18:05:00 {'OPEN': 4006.5, 'HIGH': 4007.96, 'LOW': 4006.5, 'CLOSE': 4007.95}
18:06:00 {'OPEN': 4008.02, 'HIGH': 4008.74, 'LOW': 4007.66, 'CLOSE': 4008.38}
18:07:00 {'OPEN': 4008.36, 'HIGH': 4009.46, 'LOW': 4008.36, 'CLOSE': 4009.46}
18:08:00 {'OPEN': 4009.56, 'HIGH': 4009.56, 'LOW': 4008.15, 'CLOSE': 4008.6}
18:09:00 {'OPEN': 4008.62, 'HIGH': 4010.1, 'LOW': 4008.41, 'CLOSE': 4010.07}
18:10:00 {'OPEN': 4010.04, 'HIGH': 4010.73, 'LOW': 4009.97, 'CLOSE': 4010.19}
18:11:00 {'OPEN': 4010.23, 'HIGH': 4010.25, 'LOW': 4009.32, 'CLOSE': 4010.25}
18:12:00 {'OPEN': 4010.29, 'HIGH': 4010.66, 'LOW': 4009.88, 'CLOSE': 4009.92}
```

The stream pumps different types of event, but the `MarketBarStart` only occurs at the one-minute interval (whereas there may be intermediate `MarketBarUpdate` events). Other event types may not contain all the fields eg: there may be no 'OPEN' key in the dictionary. The code keeps a running dictionary of the latest values.

The `subscribe()` function returns a dictionary (with tickers as keys) which tells you whether the subscription was successful.

The code for the `blp` wrapper is available [here](https://github.com/matthewgilbert/blp/blob/master/src/blp/blp.py), while the workings of the underlying API can be found [here](https://data.bloomberglp.com/professional/sites/10/2017/03/BLPAPI-Core-Developer-Guide.pdf) on page 41.

**EDIT:** This alternative code replicates what `blp` is doing, but instead uses the underlying `blpapi` provided by Bloomberg. It has some generic event handling, so you can see all the different events that the Bloomberg server is sending back.

**Note that the `timeout` parameter is in milli-seconds (not seconds)**, and this might actually be the cause of the OP's issue, as they have only a 120 ms wait. In my tests it can take maybe 6 seconds before the first subscription data comes through: but the OP is only allowing 3 x 120ms before giving up. Setting `timeout=0` will cause the code to block until it gets a response.

As you can see from the output with `timeout=2000`, there are still occasional timed-out waits, as Bloomberg hasn't sent any new subscription data.

```
from blpapi import Session, Event, SubscriptionList, SubscriptionPreprocessMode

evtTypes = {
    Event.ADMIN: 'ADMIN',
    Event.AUTHORIZATION_STATUS: "AUTHORIZATION_STATUS",
    Event.PARTIAL_RESPONSE: 'PARTIAL_RESPONSE',
    Event.REQUEST: 'REQUEST',
    Event.REQUEST_STATUS: 'REQUEST_STATUS',
    Event.RESOLUTION_STATUS: 'RESOLUTION_STATUS',
    Event.RESPONSE: 'RESPONSE',
    Event.SERVICE_STATUS: 'SERVICE_STATUS',
    Event.SESSION_STATUS: 'SESSION_STATUS',
    Event.SUBSCRIPTION_DATA: 'SUBSCRIPTION_DATA',
    Event.SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS: 'SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS',
    Event.TIMEOUT: 'TIMEOUT',
    Event.TOKEN_STATUS: 'TOKEN_STATUS',
    Event.TOPIC_STATUS: 'TOPIC_STATUS',
    Event.UNKNOWN: 'UNKNOWN' }

def handleEvent(evt):
    global nBarEvents

    eventType = evt.eventType()
    if eventType == Event.SUBSCRIPTION_DATA:
        nBarEvents+=1
        if nBarEvents > 2: 
            return False

        for msg in evt:
            msgType = msg.messageType()
            print(evtTypes[eventType],':',msgType)
            for elt in msg:
                print('   ',str(elt.name()) + ":" + elt.getValueAsString()) 
    else:
        print(evtTypes[eventType])

    return True #False to terminate event loop

session = Session()
session.start()

serviceName = '//blp/mktbar'

ticker = 'ES1 Index'
field = 'LAST_PRICE'
options = 'bar_size=1'

subs = SubscriptionList()
subs.add(serviceName + '/' + ticker,field,options)

res = session.subscribe(subs,mode=SubscriptionPreprocessMode.RETURN_INDIVIDUAL_ERRORS)

if len(res) == 0: #Successful subscription
    nBarEvents = 0
    bContinue = True
    while bContinue:
        bContinue = handleEvent(session.nextEvent(timeout=2000))

session.stop()
```

With this output:

```
SESSION_STATUS
SESSION_STATUS
SERVICE_STATUS
SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS
TIMEOUT
TIMEOUT
TIMEOUT
SUBSCRIPTION_DATA : MarketBarStart
    TIME:11:35:00
    OPEN:4013.750000
    HIGH:4014.000000
    LOW:4013.750000
    CLOSE:4013.750000
    NUMBER_OF_TICKS:6
    VOLUME:34
    VALUE:136471.000000
    DATE_TIME:2023-02-23T11:35:00.000+00:00
TIMEOUT
SUBSCRIPTION_DATA : MarketBarUpdate
    TIME:11:35:00
    OPEN:4013.750000
    HIGH:4014.000000
    LOW:4013.750000
    CLOSE:4014.000000
    NUMBER_OF_TICKS:7
    VOLUME:49
    VALUE:196681.000000
    DATE_TIME:2023-02-23T11:35:00.000+00:00
TIMEOUT
```

Comment: Thanks.
I see your point re need for bs.session.start(), and I do get a True returned in subs.  But then the rest still does not run on my system - and times out.  It seems that there are no events in bs.events()

I have tried running example in the code for USDCAD - under events, in the Blpstream class - and that works.  So the event handler works on my system, just not the mktbar.

Comment: @avx I've added alternative code, but I think the issue is that your timeout is too short. The parameter is in milli-seconds, not seconds, so you are only waiting a total of 3x120=360ms before giving up. Bloomberg seems to take a few seconds after the successful subscription before sending the first market bar data: standard tick data may start streaming more rapidly, which is why other subscriptions seem to work. Also, note that my example code counts the number of subscription data events only: yours also counts timeouts.

Comment: thanks DS_London!
You are right that I thought it was in seconds.  But somehow even with increasing that blp does not work on my system.  BUT, your alternative code with blpapi does work great.  So thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried with `timeout=0`? Since we have established that Bloomberg will send you bar data, then it is an issue with how you are using `blp`, not your infrastructure.

Comment: timeout=0 is not accepted as a parameter to bs.events().  I tried timeout=None, which is accepted, but still doesn't return anything, as well as no timeout parameter. 
In any case; I am happy to work with the blpapi module, and will focus on developing in that.  Next step is asyncio.